# Is this a correct use of nested function in python?

Tags: python, function, loops, nested, list-comprehension

I've just run into the following code, it's working fine but it seems weird to me since it's not even a closure, I'm wondering if it's the right way to code in terms of performance or best practices, or should all this be replaced with a regular for loop with all the logic inside ?

```
mylist = [
   {'one': 20,
    'two': 4},
   {'one': -6,
    'two': 64},
   {'one': 18,
    'two': 1},
   {'one': 16,
    'two': 100},
    # ...
]

def business_function(a_list):

    def compute_function(row):
        """
        suppose some more complex computations + appending extra values
        than this dummy example
        """
        row['total'] = row['one'] + row['two']
        return row

    def filter_function(item):
        """
        suppose some complex logic here
        """
        return item['one'] > 5

    # suppose there is some code here ...

    filtered_list = [compute_function(item) for item in a_list if filter_function(item)]

    # and some more code here ...

    return filtered_list


print business_function(mylist)
```

Comment: @JoelCornett Why put them in a broader scope when they are only relevant to a single function?

Comment: Wont comment much on the function definition part, but, I think you can use generator expression instead of list comprehension in the following line:<br>
filtered_list = (compute_function(item) for item in a_list if filter_function(item))

Comment: @delnan: Because it makes the programmer stop and go "huh?". Usually when you see functions within functions, they're factories of some sort. It makes the programmer do unnecessary double takes. That being said, I didn't mean to imply that this was *wrong* specifically, in fact I was just about to delete my comment when you replied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no problems with using locally-scoped functions like these.

Unless the outer function is going to be called *a lot* the performance impact would be minimal; the code for both functions is already compiled when the outer function is being called, for instance. All that happens *extra* is that the code object constant is loaded, attached to a function and that function is stored in a local variable.

By keeping them locally scoped you make it abundantly clear that their utility is to the `business_function` scope only.

Comment: The counterpoint is that these functions are *only* usable within `business_function()`, which means that if a similar function is required in `business_function2()` then it must be copied.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, if the function is required elsewhere it must be moved in another scope where it is accessible from all users ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say no, simply because there are better ways to do what this method desires.

- If to prevent namespace collision, put the functions in a separate module.
- If to associate with a single function, put all of them in a separate module.
- If to slow down execution, use a sleep function instead.

Otherwise just make them normal functions.

Comment: Hehe. "To slow down execution".

Comment: I concur. It's not *wrong*, but in going with the idiom "There should be one and only one obvious way to do things", this method does not immediately present itself as the "obvious" way to do any of the things you mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

There's a minor downside to this, in that the inner function objects will be created each time the enclosing function is called, which is a small performance penalty. However, this is rarely if ever a problem, and the improved encapsulation of the code may make it worthwhile.

An alternative would be to create a class, but that's not going to reduce overhead.

Comment: Since the code object isn't recreated, just the function object, the cost to do so is really minimal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like this use of nested definitions. The author maybe did this to improve readability or to prevent other people from using his private functions.

If the author wanted to "mark" these functions as private he should have prefixed their names with an underscore. In this way he could also have reused these functions in some other part of his code, without copying them.

If he did this to improve readability... well, why not putting them outside that function?
If they did some real computation and filtering, then they'd deserve to be "top level" functions with their own documentation and comments.

Probably closure should only be used in decorators, or some other *really* rare case.

Answer (score 0):

If the functions don't use local variables of the outer function and they are not trivial one-liners then I'd put them at the global scope.

Otherwise a reader of your code is forced to read all function definitions (in case they are closures and use/change outer local variables) to understand what the outer function does.

If they are defined outside then a name and possibly the corresponding docstring might be enough to understand their roles in the outer function.